# Monotouch: How to update a textfield in AppDelegate partial class?

Tags: xamarin.ios, textfield

I have a textfield (created using IB) that has an outlet connected to App Delegate.  Accessability is enabled.

I have a class for IAP, where I need to update that textfield.  It is not visible from my code.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do, you need to do 2 things:

## 1: Expose the outlet in a public property, inside your appdelegate:

```
public class AppDelegate : NSObject {
    public UITextField PublicField {
        get {
            return outletName;
        }
    }
}
```

## 2: Access your AppDelegate from another class:

```
public class OtherClass : NSObject {
    public void SomeMethod () {
        var ad = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;

        ad.PublicField.Text = "foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Put #1 inside the App Delegate partial class and am getting this error:   

Error CS0542: `Prager.AppDelegate.AppDelegate': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type (CS0542)

Comment: You only put the property into your appdelegate, not an inner class, I was just providing that as a context point, the same holds true for OtherClass.

Comment: OK.. this is what I have INSIDE App Delegate:

  public UITextField PublicField {
      get {
         return txtRemainingIDs;
      }
  }

and this is what I have inside the method where I need access:

    //  need to update the textfield on Buy IDs              <-------------------  TODO
          var ad = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    ad.txtRemainingIDs.Text = sumIDs.ToString();


and the build error is: ad.txtremainingIDs is inaccessable due to it's protection level.

I'm lost!  I thought it was right what I entered...  DO I have to do something in IB?