# Monotouch - Accessing App level variables (CS0120)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am creating an instance of something (a database class) in AppDelegate.cs and would like to access this instance from my ViewControllers.  It returns a CS0120 error, "An object reference is required to access non-static member `GeomExample.AppDelegate._db' (CS0120)"

I create my instance in AppDelegate like this:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        ...
        public Database _db;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            ...
            _db = new Database (Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "myDb.db"));
            _db.Trace = true;
```

I then try to access it like so, which generates the error:

```
IEnumerable<DbShapeElement> shapes = AppDelegate._db.GetShapeElements (_shapeName, null);
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveat: I don't know MonoTouch but reading this this question : [Monotouch: How to update a textfield in AppDelegate partial class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715488/monotouch-how-to-update-a-textfield-in-appdelegate-partial-class).

It seems to me that :

`public Database _db;` is non Static. You need to use the instance of the AppDelegate that you have.

Try this:

```
var ad = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
IEnumerable<DbShapeElement> shapes = ad._db.GetShapeElements (_shapeName, null);
```

**Edit:**

Instead of using a public instance variable, it's cleaner to use a property with a private setter to prevent modification outside the AppDelegate class:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    ...
    public Database Db {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ...
        Db = new Database (Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "myDb.db"));
        Db.Trace = true;
        ...
```

then you access it like this outside the AppDelegate class:

```
var ad = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
IEnumerable<DbShapeElement> shapes = ad.Db.GetShapeElements (_shapeName, null);
```

Comment: You are 100% right!  You've missed your calling, take up Monotouch development :)

Comment: @Glinkot - Thank you lol. I actually have a license for MonoTouch but no OSX box yet. Maybe Father Xmas will be kind this year.

Comment: Just a cosmetic issue, but the name of public members should not start with underscores and it's also cleaner to use a property like `public DataBase Db { get; private set; }`.  This ensures that the value can only be modified from within the AppDelegate class.

Comment: @MartinBaulig - thanks - you should just edit the answer to provide that info.